# Telerik jQuery conflict asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik along with regular jQuery UI.

I have include files like this,

JQuery:

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Telerik

I tried,

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() %>
```

and

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).jQueryValidation(false) %>
```

With *jQuery(false).jQueryValidation(false)* I am getting error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'

without *jQuery(false).jQueryValidation(false)* i.e with <%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() %>

The jQuery UI is not working. Error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'button'

```
<button id="Button1">Button1</button>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#Button1").button().click(function () {
                location.href = '/One/Two';
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the same (or very similar) problem that we had after setting up Telerik.  I'm assuming the scripts and telerik code you posted above is all on your master page(or layout)?  Try deleting

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() %>
```

from the master page and paste it to the bottom of each individual view that actually uses a telerik control.  That is what worked for us.